# Photon OnRoomPropertiesUpdate not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have a simple method which update the custom properties(via Photonnetwork.CurrentRoom.setCustomProperties(hashtable) ).
It gets updated on the local player who called it (where as the OnRoomPropertiesUpdate  method doesn't get callled) but the other players in the room don't get get the change.
Please help.

```
 // method that i call to update custom properties
 public void sync_state(int value)
 {
     ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable hash = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties;
     Debug.Log("SYnCING ====  Value: "+hash["val"]+
     hash["val"] = value;
     PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(hash);
  }


// this method never gets called.
 public override void OnRoomPropertiesUpdate(ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable propertiesThatChanged)
   {
    Debug.Log("Room properties updated ");

     /// my other code
    UPDATE_GAME_STATE(propertiesThatChanged);


}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for choosing Photon! Make sure all clients are joined to the same room. Make sure you call `base.OnEnable` if you override `OnEnable` in `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks`.